# extension of the property of a set to its generated $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

*Theorem*: Suppose that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space and that $c \subset \mathcal{F}$ is such that

1. $c$ contains $\Omega$.
2. $c$ is closed under intersection.(i.e.$A \cap B \in c$, if $A,B \in c$)

If $\mu$ and $v$ are a pair of finite measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ and $\mu(A)=v(A)$ for each $A \in c$, then $\mu(A)=v(A)$ for any $A \in \sigma(c)$.

*Prove this Theorem.*

I have tried to construct a $\mathcal{F_1}=\{A \subset \mathbb{R}|\mu(A)=v(A)\}$. If $\mathcal{F_1}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then the theorem can be easily proved.
Obviously,
$\mathcal{F_1}$ is closed under complementary and $\phi,\Omega \in \mathcal{F_1}$.

Therefore, we only need to show that $\mathcal{F_1}$ is countably additive. But I don't know how to prove it or how to use the second property of $c$.

Comment: The theorem is missing in your question

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net my mistake

Comment: It is enough to prove countable additive for disjoint sets. Then $\mu(\bigcup A_n ) = \sum_n \mu(A_n) = \sum_n \nu(A_n) = \nu(\bigcup A_n)$

Comment: If $\{S_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal{F}_1$ then: $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_n\right)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mu(S_n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\upsilon(S_n)=\upsilon\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n\right).$$

Comment: @Yanko I don't understand... Why is it enough to prove countable additivity for disjoint sets?

Comment: @kelvinchung do you know if it is closed under finite unions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer: It is enough to show that $\mathcal{F}_1$ is closed under finite unions.

To prove that the set is closed under countable unions observe that if $A_1,A_2,...\in \mathcal{F}_1$ are disjoint then $$\mu(\bigcup A_n ) = \sum_n \mu(A_n) = \sum_n \nu(A_n) = \nu(\bigcup A_n)$$

Now let  $A_1,A_2,...,$ countably many sets in your family (not necessarily disjoint).

Then consider the following sets

Let $A_1' = A_1$ and by induction let $A_i' = A_i \backslash \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1} A_i$

by finite additivity you get that all $A_i'$ are in your set, also they are disjoint and $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i'$. This completes the proof assuming that you know that the family is closed under finite unions.

For finite unions I don't know what to do. But observe that using a proof by induction it is enough to show that if $A$ and $B$ are in $\mathcal{F}$ then $A\cup B$ is in $\mathcal{F}$. Since $\mu(A\cup B) = \mu(A)+\mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B)$ it is enough to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under finite intersections.

Comment: emm I don't understand why $A_i^{'}$ are in $\mathcal{F_1}$

Comment: @kelvinchung I had a small mistake and it should be a back-slash instead of an intersection. If you know that finite unions are in $\mathcal{F_1}$ then $\bigcup_{j=1}^{j-1}A_i$ are in $\mathcal{F}_1$. Lets call this set $B$, we want to show that if $A$ and $B$ are in $\mathcal{F}_1$ then $A\backslash B$ is. Observe that $A\backslash B = A\cap \Omega\backslash B = \Omega\backslash ( \Omega\backslash A \cup B)$ since $\mathcal{F}_1$ is closed to complements, $\Omega\backslash A\in \mathcal{F}_1$ and so $ \Omega\backslash A \cup B\in\mathcal{F}_1$. Taking a complement again you have what you want